# Pipeline Transform Logging on Apache Beam in Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, logging, apache-beam, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

Recently, I deployed a very simple Apache Beam pipeline to get some insights into how it behaved executing in Dataproc as opposed to on my local machine. I quickly realized that after executing that any `DoFn` or transform-level logging didn't appear within the job logs within the Google Cloud Console as I would have expected and I'm not entirely sure what might be missing.

All of the high level logging messages are emitted as expected:

```
// This works
log.info("Testing logging operations...")

pipeline
    .apply(Create.of(...))
    .apply(ParDo.of(LoggingDoFn))
```

The `LoggingDoFn` class here is a very basic transform that emits each of the values that it encounters as seen below:

```
object LoggingDoFn : DoFn<String, ...>() {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingDoFn::class.java)
    
    @ProcessElement
    fun processElement(c: ProcessContext) {
        // This is never emitted within the logs
        log.info("Attempting to parse ${c.element()}")
    }
}
```

As detailed in the comments, I can see logging messages outside of the `processElement()` calls (presumably because those are being executed by the Spark runner), but is there a way to easily expose those within the inner transform as well? When viewing the logs related to this job, we can see the higher-level logging present, but no mention of a "Attempting to parse ..." message from the `DoFn`:

[image: GCP Logging]

The job itself is being executed by the following `gcloud` command, which has the driver log levels explicitly defined, but perhaps there's another level of logging or configuration that needs to be added:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --jar=gs://some_bucket/deployment/example.jar --project example-project --cluster example-cluster --region us-example --driver-log-levels com.example=DEBUG -- --runner=SparkRunner --output=gs://some_bucket/deployment/out
```

To summarize, log messages are not being emitted to the Google Cloud Console for tasks that would generally be assigned to the Spark runner itself (e.g. `processElement()`). I'm unsure if it's a configuration-related issue or something else entirely.

Comment: Hi Rion, I understand that the logs of the processElement paralellized function might not be appearing within the Job output because they are part of the worker logs. Did you attempt to SSH into the container to access the logs directly?